# map from_plugin routes in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, routes

Currently I am running my app on Rails 2.3.8 and decided to move it to Rails 3.
I have a route in `routes.rb`.

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  map.from_plugin :substruct
end
```

I could not find equivalent format in Rails 3. How do I modify that ?

Comment: have a look at work re: substrcut and Rails 3: https://github.com/rubyjedi/substruct_app/wiki

Answer (score 1):

As of Rails 2.3 map.from_plugin is deprecated as it auto handles the mappings for newer plugins.

As glongman said in the comment to your questions please check the [Basic Substruct App](https://github.com/rubyjedi/substruct_app/wiki)  which is a basic demo application to allow the new Substruct Plugin fork for Rails to work.

Comment: and @glongman, can either of you elaborate (explain, links to docs, even links to specific source files) on how one would convert from using "from_plugin" routing to whatever one does to achieve the same end in Rails 3.  The link you provide is to a Rails app (which itself contains links to a related Rails engine).  Can you be a bit more specific?  I've been reading the source code of these projects and I haven't yet figured it out.